# Reading a text file into a variable in shell script

Tags: shell

Hello I'm trying to save a text file(let's call it file.dat (it's a UTF-8 Unicode text) into a variable in a script I'm making. I want to call the file.dat like : ./myscript file.dat (or something similar).
Having a command line in code in the form of variable=file.dat won't help.

I'm new to shell so I apologize if the question is not very specific

Comment: `var=$(<"$1")` should work in `bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
var=$(cat $1)
```

then var will contain the content of your file

Answer (score 5):

Some thing like this should get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

content=$(cat "$1")  # This is how you slurp the content of the file

echo "Content of $1:"
echo "$content"
```